# php mysqli with multiple tables and math

Tags: php, mysql

ok so i have 3 tables we can call them A B and C so table A has a list (item 1, Item 2)  i need to read each row and filter using tables A item 1 and item 2 then for each row return on B i need to filter C and take the 1st 5 returns and get the avg out of cell 2. here is how it look doing it by hand

Table A

```
33004   1   33003   1

33006   1   33005   1

33008   1   33007   1

33010   1   33009   1

33012   1   33011   1

33067   1   33017   1

33077   1   33076   1

33088   1   33087   1

33102   1   33101   1

33104   1   33103   1
```

So table `b` after filter (`33010`) should look alike

```
33010   1   34  2222

33010   1   35  2222
```

so the mysql would be `"SELECT * FROM`B`WHERE`typeID`= 33010 "` i need php to plug in the `33010`

after that i need to move on to table `C` so i need to filter for `34` and `35` for each of them i will have to get the first 5 rows and cell 3 and get the avg and then `*` that by table B 4 cell for each

can anyone point me in the right place to start

Comment: Are table b and c physical tables or the result of a query? It's difficult to understand without getting an idea of the structure of these tables.

Comment: Also in table A, are there 4 fields or 2?

Comment: they are physical tables and A has 4

Comment: Ok - what do each of the columns mean in each table? I'm having a hard time understanding how in your example A filters into B

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4PbCaECyXU&feature=youtu.be the tables are show are C B A

Comment: the filter is the type id